# Parsing into Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, dictionary

I could nt be able to parse the following JSON response.Here my code

```
{
"result": "Success",
"data": "[
 {
    "name": "heal.jpg",
    "date": "2014-11-06 05:06:42"
},
{
    "name": "google.png",
    "date": "2014-11-06 05:09:17"
},
{
    "name": "d.jpg",
    "date": "2014-11-10 06:57:16"
}
]",
"msg": ""
}
```

Code

```
 NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSArray *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];
     NSDictionary *onlineReadingdata = [jsonData valueForKeyPath:@"data"];
      NSLog(@"Array Disctionary %@",onlineReadingdata);
   for (NSDictionary *details in onlineReadingdata) 
      {
         NSLog(@"name %@",[details valueForKey:@"name"]);
         NSLog(@"date %@",[details valueForKey:@"date"]);
     }
```

Comment: isn't your JSON missing the starting and ending `{`/`}` ?

Comment: i have missed to add in question, i added now

Comment: It's `JSONObjectWithData:`, not `JSONObjectWithString:`.  Why do you convert a (presumably) perfectly good NSData object to NSString and try to parse that??

Comment: And as Seryozha points out, the JSON listing you're showing us is bogus.  I find it hard to believe you could have even arranged to produce such a list if you had intended to, since the quotes inside the "array" are not escaped.  I'm guessing you pasted it together from bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is invalid. JSON arrays are written inside square brackets. 
Remove double quotation marks (") before and after square brackets.